# Why MySQL DB connector with EF 4.1 code first fails every first time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, mysql-connector

Whenever my MVC/"EF 4.1 code first" web application tries to access the data base for the first time it gives me the following exception:

```
[MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user 'SomeUser'@'94.45.23.90' (using password: NO)]
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +250
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.AuthenticateNew(Boolean reset) +482
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +1186
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() +245
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) +294
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection() +18
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() +403
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() +228
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() +106
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +1251
System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +67
[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +11109774
System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +142
System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +97
System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +66
System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +47
System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +220
System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +383
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.QueryForModelHash() +349
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata) +109
System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +360
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +64
[DataException: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.]
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +152
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +199
System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +193
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +235
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +39
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +89
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +21
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +44
System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +135
Got.Data.Infrastructure.RepositoryBase`2.GetMany(Expression`1 where) in C:\Users\Eran\Documents\ForumTel\GotMvcConvert\Got.Data\Infrastructure\RepositoryBase.cs:79
Got.Services.ProductService.GetSignUpProducts() in C:\Users\Eran\Documents\ForumTel\GotMvcConvert\Got.Services\ProductService.cs:27
Got.Web.Controllers.HomeController.Products(Nullable`1 category) in C:\Users\Eran\Documents\ForumTel\GotMvcConvert\Got.Web\Controllers\HomeController.cs:37
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +118
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +264
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +129
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +826410
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +826410
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +826410
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +314
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +825632
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +335
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +54
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +469
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

After I refresh the page it works fine. But after every compilation/application unload, I get this exception for the first DB load.

I use MySql connector v6.4.3.0.

How can I solve that?

Comment: it's an access denied:

> Access denied for user 'SomeUser'@'94.45.23.90'

where in your code you are establishing the first data connection? could it be that after you started the web application and logged in the current user, it simply works because there is an active user?

Comment: I use static connection string. I use EF ctor to use it: `public SomeDbContext() : base("SomeConnectionString")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's fixed in MySQL connector v6.4.4.0.